# How to break while loop inside a function when condition is based on calling of other function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, signalr, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

I am using Signalr Core client in Python by: https://github.com/mandrewcito/signalrcore

I am using chat example from the git source above and modified it for my application.

I am trying to put a while loop in a function, where the condition of while loop should break when another function is called. But it gets stuck in the while loop.

Here is my code:

```py
from signalrcore.hub_connection_builder import HubConnectionBuilder


def input_with_default(input_text, default_value):
    value = input(input_text.format(default_value))
    return default_value if value is None or value.strip() == "" else value

def start_msg(msg):
     while end_event.has_been_called == False:        
          Print("Starting")
          sleep(1)

def end_event(endmsg):
     end_event.has_been_called = True
     pass    
     print("End Event")


server_url = input_with_default('Enter your server url(default: {0}): ', "ws://localhost:62342/chathub")
username = input_with_default('Enter your username (default: {0}): ', "sam")

hub_connection = HubConnectionBuilder().with_url(server_url).with_automatic_reconnect({
        "type": "raw",
        "keep_alive_interval": 10,
        "reconnect_interval": 5,
        "max_attempts": 5
    }).build()
end_event.has_been_called = False
hub_connection.on("StartEvent", start_msg)
hub_connection.on("EndEvent", end_event)
hub_connection.start()
message = None
# Do login

while message != "exit()":
    message = input(">> ")
    if message is not None and message is not "" and message is not "exit()":
        hub_connection.send("SendMessage", [username, message])
hub_connection.stop()
```

In this code, when it receives a message with StartEvent, it goes into start_msg function and starts printing "Starting", but as soon as EndEvent is received it should go to end_event function but it just gets stuck in while loop and never breaks out of it.

If I remove the while loop then it works fine, but I need it to stay in while loop inside start_msg until end_event is called.

How can I achieve this?

**Edit:** Just to clarify, I am referring to this while loop:

```
def start_msg(msg):
 while end_event.has_been_called == False:        
      Print("Starting")
      sleep(1)
```

Comment: Raise an exception. It will propagate to the calling code, where you can catch and handle it.

Comment: You can make your condition a bit more compact by writing `if message not in (None, "", "exit()"):`.

Comment: @TomLubenow can you please give an example. Thanks

Comment: Side-note: You almost never want to compare to `True` or `False` directly (and in the rare cases you do, you'd use `is`/`is not`, rather than `==`/`!=`); it's slower than just testing implicit truthiness, and with `==`/`!=`, it's no more type safe (since `True` is equal to `1`, `1.0`, etc., while `False` is equal to `0`, `0.0`, etc.). `while end_event.has_been_called == False:` should be spelled `while not end_event.has_been_called:`

Comment: On same `Thread` ? no way ! How to check exceptions on more than one `loop` ? Priority is very important, The state machine is easy to do if you can run sub-processes. Create two sub-processes and share their change flags. Personal thought: I think you'll be a very good programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would address your if statement

Rather than complicating your if statement, assign a list

`conditions = [None, "", "exit()"]`

Then you can do

`if message not in conditions:`

Which would allow you to expand your conditions if you had to. Also a little more elegant IMO

Secondly, I would make this a class. `end_event.has_been_called` is assigning an attribute to a function, which is wierd.

Lastly, Your start event should call your end event. Unless this module runs async somehow (I did not install it), you will never get to your `end_event` function call, so you're stuck in your loop. Hope this helps

```
from signalrcore.hub_connection_builder import HubConnectionBuilder

class Event_Handler:

    def __init__(self):
        self.conditions = [None, "", "exit()"]
        self.end_call = False

    def input_with_default(self, input_text, default_value):
        value = input(input_text.format(default_value))
        return default_value if value is None or value.strip() == "" else value

    def start_msg(self, msg):
         while self.end_call == False:
              print("Starting")
              self.end_event('Ending')
              sleep(1)

    def end_event(self, endmsg):
         self.end_call = True
         pass
         print("End Event")

    def run_server(self):
        server_url = input_with_default('Enter your server url(default: {0}): ', "ws://localhost:62342/chathub")
        username = input_with_default('Enter your username (default: {0}): ', "sam")

        hub_connection = HubConnectionBuilder().with_url(server_url).with_automatic_reconnect({
                "type": "raw",
                "keep_alive_interval": 10,
                "reconnect_interval": 5,
                "max_attempts": 5
            }).build()
        self.end_call = False
        hub_connection.on("StartEvent", start_msg)
        hub_connection.on("EndEvent", end_event)
        hub_connection.start()
        message = None
        # Do login

        while message != "exit()":
            message = input(">> ")
            if message not in self.conditions:
                hub_connection.send("SendMessage", [username, message])
        hub_connection.stop()
```